# Favorite tags on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, tag-watching

When browsing questions on the website you see your favorite tags on the right hand side of the screen. A really convenient way to quickly filter questions on a tag that I am interested in. However this feature is lacking on the question page of the mobile site, probably due to the design.

So I went exploring for a way to easily find my favorited tags. I had a look under the Tags page and was surprised they weren't there either. I sorted on all three options: "popular", "name", and "new", but in all cases it required me to scroll through the list to find them.

Why can't we just add the tags we favortied as a fourth ranking order? Or perhaps easier to implement, put them on top of the "popular" sort, as my favorite tags are also my most popular tags. Who cares about JavaScript or Java anyway? ;)

Comment: Although favorite tags are missing visually, you can still use them on mobile, you just have to type them in manually in the search bar, wrapped in brackets, ie `[tag]`.

Comment: Ofcourse you can @RemyLebeau, and for a tag like [C++] that might not be that much work, but for [excel-vba] I will have to switch my keyboard to secondary keys 5 times...