# Making 'ignore tag' option easily discoverable

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Currently, clicking on the star **twice** adds the tag to the ignored list. Yes, it's easy when you know it, but it's not easily discoverable. I had to google it to find out.

#### Current way

[image: Current way]

#### A better way?

Seeing a gray star, my instincts tells me that it's a two-state toggle button (ON or OFF). Star is the icon for favorites anyway. Can we keep the star as it is and move the third state to a different link? More like this?

[image: A better way]

Comment: I never knew you could ignore tags. If I had hit it twice, I would have expected it was just on/off the favorites list. I definitely think a separate ignore option would be ideal. Now I wonder if I'm ignoring any tags by accident.

Comment: you can click on edit in your favourite tag list in the right.. It allows you to add any tag to ignore list as well

Comment: Yes @Suraj Rao, but this is about the shortcut

Comment: This is **awful** UX. Common sense suggests that it's just a toggle between adding a tag to the favorites and removing it from them.

Comment: Wow, after using the site for four years, I just learned I can ignore tags. 0.o Also TIL, ignoring a tag does not actually hide posts, but just makes them more translucent. Not really helpful.

Comment: @BaummitAugen you can entirely hide ignored tags from settings.

Comment: @nipunasudha Nice, thanks for the info! Now that actually does help.

Comment: Also vaguely related, make it easy to find your favorite tags on the mobile site: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360612/favorite-tags-on-mobile-site

Comment: Well, you know what happens if you try to do multiple things at once https://i.imgur.com/cgJwbNE.gif  
It's really bad UX, and I wouldn't even have considered anyone would have the bright idea that this could be a good place to put this...